# Error: No candidate version found for kvm

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization

I'm following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) to install `KVM` on my machine to make `Android Emulators` run faster, I have `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` installed on my machine. I have done all the steps correctly until this one:

```
sudo aptitude install kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

When I run this command to install `Karmic` I get this error:

```
No candidate version found for kvm       
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
```

**What is the problem? How to fix it?**

Comment: Change the `kvm` to `qemu-kvm`.  You accidentally read the line for 9.10 and older.  You are running 10.04 or newer.

Comment: I did it, but I have two groups now: `libvirt-qemu` and `libvirt-dnsmasq`, but not `libvirt`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Just manually create the required group and then add yourself to the group as per the instructions in the manual.

```
sudo addgroup libvirtd
sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd
```